# How to change the value of a cell in a unbound column of a databound DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a databound DataGridView which is connected to my MySQL database.  Through the designer, I have set 10 columns which, upon loading are filled correctly.

In the designer, I have added 2 additional columns which are not connected to any data source (unbound).  I want to population these 2 columns with content (numbers) that I created a method for in order to calculate a 'weekly revenue'.

I have tried to do the simple method of:

```vb
datagridview1.row(0).cells(target_Cell).value = 'weekly revenue'
```

It did not throw me any errors but nothing additional showed up on the DataGridView in my target cell.

I also tried adding it to the DataSet, but I was thrown in error because my target column was not part of the MySQL database table.  I do not want to add it to the database table.

Any advice on how I can get my unbound columns to update and show this information?

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to fill the DataTable, then add your 2 columns and populate them.  When you bind the DT, the columns will be there with the data.  It is almost always better to act/loop on/work with the *data* than the control

Comment: When I bind the database to my datagridview through the designer, it automatically adds this method to my frmMain_Load: "Me.Master_projectTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PalladiumDataSet.master_project)"  Is this what you mean by filling the DataTable?  if so, do I add the 2 columns programmatically? or can I still do it through the designer like I currently am?